# About Android pull to refresh library

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

I am using pull-to-refresh library for Android, this one in particular:

https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/blob/master/library/src/com/handmark/pulltorefresh/library/PullToRefreshListView.java

Now this might sound little ironic, but I want to disable 'pull to refresh' programatically at some point, that is to disable pull gestures triggering that 'loading' header animation on the top, basically i want the pull to refresh list to start behaving like a normal list after that.

Anyone ? Thank you very much, like for real.

Comment: Did you try setting the scroll listener to null? setOnScrollListener(null) after the first refresh is complete.

Comment: I believe i tried that already :\

Comment: You can replace your pulltorefresh Listview to default Listview

Answer (score 4):

You should try to play with `Mode` :

```
// Disable pullToRefresh 
mListView.setMode(Mode.DISABLE);

// enable pullToRefresh
mListView.setMode(Mode.PULL_FROM_START);
```